# It is ROS being used in the aerospace industry?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is the case, I would appreciate if you could give me some examples.

Thanks, guys!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272173/it-is-ros-being-used-in-the-aerospace-industry?/) by [masterile](https://answers.ros.org/users/32049/masterile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
Personally, I can only say "yes" (and not much more, as companies in that sector are typically not too open about what they do and don't use).

But I feel you'll get better answers than this if you clarify a bit more what you mean with "aerospace industry". It's rather broad.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
You're probably not going to get much more than a "yes." Unless an aerospace company is doing open research, which is rare. You can check job postings from different companies and see if any of them require/desire knowledge of ROS.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
You can see that NASA has (and maybe still is) used it:

- https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20130013586.pdf
- http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/ros-running-on-iss.html

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-10-03**:
[Tecnalia with Airbus](http://www.ros.org/news/2013/01/tecnalia-wins-the-factory-of-the-future-award-at-european-manufacturing-awards-2012-with-a-robot-pro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Boeing is a sponsor of ROS-Industrial: http://rosindustrial.org/news/2015/8/19/scan-n-plan-for-robotic-blending-milestone-3, and Airbus and GKN Aerospace are listed on http://rosindustrial.org/ric/current-members/ (it would be nice instead of an image full of logos there were clickable links to the different companies, and some of them are too small to read...).

It doesn't mean they are using ROS internally necessarily, but the interest is there.

I scanned through the ROSCon sponsors https://roscon.ros.org/2017/ (+1 for clickable logos) but didn't see anything.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1